# Nested Observables: adding an observable as a property of an observable and unwrapping it

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I am trying to create a function that takes user data as an Observable and add / merge data from a query using data from the first observable then return all this data as one observable, I can do this, but cannot operate on the return nested of observable

Here is a function that returns an observable with an observable as a property on it called holidays

```
getAllUsersWithHolidays() {
  return this.users.map(items => {
   for (let item of items) {
    item.holiday = this.af.database.list('Holiday',
      {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'userIdKey',
          equalTo: item.$key
        }
      }
    )
   }
  return items;
 });
}
```

The problem arises when I call try to pull out the data stored on holiday

```
this.summary$ = this.UserListService.getUserByEmail().mergeMap(user => { //get the user details to filter by team
  return this.HolidayService.getAllUserWithHolidays().map(data => {
    return data
    .filter(team => team.team === user[0].team) //filters users by team
    .map(item => { //map over combined data
      return item.holiday
      .map(hol => { // Hol is observable, build with property daysTaken
          return {
            firstname: item.firstname,
            surname: item.surname,
            holiday: hol.reduce((prev, curr) => {prev + curr.daysTaken, 0) //cannot access hol data        
          }
      });         
    });
  })
})
```

Then unwrap with async

```
 {{summary$ | async | json}}
```

When mapping over the holiday observable, it seems that I cannot access data? Perhaps because I'm not subscribed yet?

I'd rather not have an observable as a property returned from the getAllUsersWithHolidays I would rather calculate it first

so instead of this returning items as this

```
{user: 'exampleName', holiday:fireBaseListObservable}
```

I would return it already calculated

```
{ user:'exampleName' , holiday: 20 }
```

But doing this has also eluded me...

```
getAllUsersWithHolidays() {
  return this.users.map(items => {
   for (let item of items) {
    item.holiday = this.af.database.list('Holiday',
      {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'userIdKey',
          equalTo: item.$key
        }
      }
    ).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.daysTaken, 0)
   }
  return items;
 });
}
```

I thought I could do it like this, but this still returns an observable and of course I cannot subscribe here and return anything, that never seems to work!

Comment: flatMap is your friend

Comment: flatMap is just another name for mergeMap which is used in the correct answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `mergeMap` to unroll the nested observables from getUsers -> usersWithHolidays, you just need an additional `mergeMap` to unroll the holidays for each user.  The only complication is that your nested observables are properties of your objects.  So we can use `Observable.from()` to handle that.

```
getAllUsersWithHolidays() {
  return this.users.mergeMap(items => {
   return Observable
       .from(items)
       .mergeMap(item => this.af.database.list(...)
          .map(holiday => {
               return {
                  ...item,
                  holiday
               };
           })
       );
  });
}
```

Comment: I have reproduced this, the angularfire Query isn't giving me anything back with 'holiday' but replacing this with a test Observable.from[1,2,3] does show me that it works, so thanks. I will have to see why mapping over an angularfire query doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an observable stream that is emitting observables. Sounds horrible, but don't worry, RxJS can deal with this.

The top level observable stream is called the higher order observable. The observables being emitted are called inner observables.

To get at the values being emitted from the inner observables (instead of the inner observables themselves) you should use switchMap.

switchMap is more friendly than flatMap as, if there is an outstanding innerObservable, switch map will cancel it and instead emit from the latest inner observable. This is handy for http observables.

flatMap will not cancel previous streams and so you will find emits from ALL inner observables.

Comment: That's a good point but it seems like it wouldn't be a question of convenience but of correctness. It all depends on the use case.